# Is the MetaMask App Reliable?

Tags: wallets

I found there is a new metamask app on apple store, is this app open source and reliable? Since there are a lot of various wallets for app, which one is reliable?

Answer (score 0):

> I found there is a new metamask app on apple store, is this app open source...

Yes, it's open-source, but you will want to read the [licence](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/blob/develop/LICENSE). (You may also want to read the changes that will be happening to the licence: [Evolving our License for the Next Wave of MetaMask Users](https://medium.com/metamask/evolving-our-license-for-the-next-wave-of-metamask-users-81b0b494c09a).)

> ...and reliable?

Depends what you mean by "reliable".

If you're asking how to check that you're running a legitimate version of the extension, then you'll need to compare the namespace of the extension you're running against the one published by the Metamask team.

This is described in detail in this article: [How to Ensure You’re Running the Legitimate Version of MetaMask](https://medium.com/mycrypto/how-to-ensure-youre-running-the-legitimate-version-of-metamask-5fcd8ab32b96)

If you're asking whether Metamask is a reliable app, then you'll need to qualify what you mean by the term "reliable". Reliability can mean different things to different people.

Comment: Thanks，actually I mean whether my assets are safe if I store them in MetaMask app? Is it not centralized?